# can not return to parent activity from child activity opened by menu in Android App

Tags: android-activity, menu, return, parent

```
    manifest:
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="com.boropost.app.MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".FindActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="com.boropost.app.MainActivity" />
   menu:
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_find"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

In my case, the child SettingsActivity is opened via a menu item that is not showed on the action bar. Clicking the back button does not return to the parent MainActivity. The onActivityCreated in MainActivity is not triggered neither, however the child FindActivity that is opened via a menu item that is showed on the action bar does not have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Please add below lines on onCrate() method

```
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

> And Add below method in your child SettingsActivity

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
               finish();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Are you extending AppComaptActivity?

Comment: yes, it looks somehow when the menu button on the action bar, it remember the parent activity, but not if it is on the drop down menu.

Comment: Can you send me a screenshot of that?